# Acer Iconia B1-710 connecting to TV using HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I've tried connecting my Acer Iconia B1-710 to the tv using a USB/HDMI cable but the tv will not recognise the signal!

What else do I need to do to get the image to appear on the tablet and TV simultaneously

Comment: I have the A1-810 & it has micro HDMI to connect a micro HDMI to HDMI connector. There is also a mini HDMI connector in total 3 sizes in HDMI connections Mini, Micro & regular HDMI connections!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a USB to HDMI cable the device needs to support Mobile High-Definition Link ([MHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link)), which, unfortunately, the Iconia B1-710 does not.

Some devices have their own proprietary cables for connecting, but, according to [this Acer forum thread](http://community.acer.com/t5/2014-Archives/Connecting-my-iconia-b1-710-to-my-TV/td-p/185267):

> We do not support connecting the B1-710 tablet to a television via USB. There are no products that I am aware of that would facilitate this connectivity.